# forgot bitlocker key and recovery file

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I am using window 7 OS. and some time ago i used bit locker to lock my F drive.now, i want to access it at that time it's asking me for key which i forgot to unlock bit locker.

Also, i re install my OS. but still there.

so, how can i get my recovery key or get the data of locked drive?
i was thinking to use "ubantu" live CD & try to access locked drive. it will be work?

Thanks

Comment: If this were possible, what would the point of bitlocker be?

Comment: Encryption guarantees that a drive is unrecoverable no matter what OS is used in the attempt unless you know the credentials used to encrypt. That's the whole point. If you don't intend on safely backing up the credentials and keeping them in safe storage, don't encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

good encryption protects data against unauthorized access. if it would be easy to decrypt: what is the point of the encryption in the first place? every jon doe might come along.

if you have lost the key: you are (from the perspective of the encrypted disc) the attacker. no key, no access to the data. if you have lost the key: bad luck, the data is unaccessible to you. forever.

Comment: if i use ubuntu live CD & get the locked drive?

Comment: if i have to get registry file than how can i get it?

Comment: if you do not have the key: you are the attacker. if you do not know the key: the encrypted data is pure white noise. end of story.

the purpose of "encryption" is to protect the data from folks with an "ubauntu cd".

Comment: ohhh........ :(

Answer (score 0):

Source [BitLocker Drive Encryption in Windows 7: Frequently Asked Questions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449438%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> ### If I lose my recovery information, will the BitLocker-protected data be unrecoverable?
>
> **BitLocker is designed to make the encrypted drive unrecoverable without the required authentication.**
>
> When in recovery mode, the user needs the recovery password or
>   recovery key to unlock the encrypted drive.
>
> **Therefore, we highly recommend that you store the recovery information in AD DS or in another safe location.**